# How to connecting kafka to mysql?

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am Trying to connect kafka with mysql on windows. I am not using confluent. My kafka version is 2.12 I have started zookeeper, Kafka, producer and consumer, This all works fine.

My MysQL version is 8.0.15

And I have copied this 3 jar files in the libs folder

```
mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.47-bin.jar
```

My source-quickstart-mysql.properties file code is

```
name=test-source-mysql-jdbc-autoincrement        connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename? 
user=rootname&password=password
mode=incrementing
incrementing.column.name=ID
topic.prefix=my-replicated-topic-table1
```

When I run the command

```
connect-standalone.bat ..\..\config\connect-standalone.properties  ..\..\config\source-quickstart-mysql.properties
```

I am getting this Error on console

> [2019-03-26 16:16:39,524] ERROR Failed to create job for ....\config\source-quickstart-mysql.properties
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone)
>               [2019-03-26 16:16:39,524] ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone)
>               java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to find any
>   class that implements Connector and which name matches
>   io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourc
>               eConnector, available connectors are: PluginDesc{klass=class
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector,
>   name='org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector',
>   version='2.1.0', encod
>               edVersion=2.1.0, type=sink, typeName='sink', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector,
>   name='org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSource
>               Connector', version='2.1.0', encodedVersion=2.1.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'},
>   PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockConnector,
>   name='org.apache.kafka.co
>               nnect.tools.MockConnector', version='2.1.0', encodedVersion=2.1.0, type=connector, typeName='connector',
>   location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector,
>                name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector', version='2.1.0', encodedVersion=2.1.0, type=sink, typeName='sink',
>   location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.tool
>               s.MockSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector',
>   version='2.1.0', encodedVersion=2.1.0, type=source, typeName='source',
>   location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class o
>               rg.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector',
>   version='2.1.0', encodedVersion=2.1.0, type=source, typeName='source',
>   location='class
>               path'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector,
>   name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector',
>   version='2.1.0', encodedVersion=2.1.0, type=source
>               , typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector,
>   name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector',
>   version='2
>               .1.0', encodedVersion=2.1.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}
>                       at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.result(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:79)
>                       at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.get(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:66)
>                       at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:110)
>               Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to find any
>   class that implements Connector and which name matches
>   io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector, available connecto
>               rs are: PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector,
>   name='org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector',
>   version='2.1.0', encodedVersion=2.1.0, type=sink, ty
>               peName='sink', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector,
>   name='org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector',
>   version='2.1.0', e
>               ncodedVersion=2.1.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockConnector,
>   name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockConnector', ve
>               rsion='2.1.0', encodedVersion=2.1.0, type=connector, typeName='connector', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector,
>   name='org.apache.kafka.connec
>               t.tools.MockSinkConnector', version='2.1.0', encodedVersion=2.1.0, type=sink, typeName='sink',
>   location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector, name='o
>               rg.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector', version='2.1.0', encodedVersion=2.1.0, type=source, typeName='source',
>   location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.
>               SchemaSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector',
>   version='2.1.0', encodedVersion=2.1.0, type=source, typeName='source',
>   location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class
>                org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector',
>   version='2.1.0', encodedVersion=2.1.0, type=source, typeName='source',
>   location=
>               'classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector,
>   name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector',
>   version='2.1.0', encodedVersion=2.1.0, t
>               ype=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}
>                       at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.newConnector(Plugins.java:179)
>                       at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.getConnector(AbstractHerder.java:382)
>                       at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.validateConnectorConfig(AbstractHerder.java:261)
>                       at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder.putConnectorConfig(StandaloneHerder.java:189)
>                       at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:107)

Please help me.

I have also tried this article but no output generated with command 
    bin/confluent load jdbc-source -d jdbc-source.properties
https://supergloo.com/kafka-connect/kafka-connect-mysql-example/

Comment: I am sorry. I am new to stack overflow. Please ignore the indentation. Thank You

Comment: Possible duplicate of [kafka jdbc sink connector standalone error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54417979/kafka-jdbc-sink-connector-standalone-error)

Comment: check that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54417979/kafka-jdbc-sink-connector-standalone-error/54418530#54418530

Answer (score 1):

Your error is

```
 org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to find any class that 
 implements Connector and which name matches io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
```

Which since you say you're not using Confluent Platform makes sense, because kafka-connect-jdbc is not part of Apache Kafka. You can either use Confluent Platform, build the connector from [source](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/), or download it at http://hub.confluent.io.

Comment: I am getting a new error. This time my database is in another Linux node lets suppose xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:3306 and I am running the standalone command of kafka connect from my Windows machine. My server.properties code is name=test-source-mysql-jdbc-autoincrement connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector tasks.max=1 connection.url=jdbc:mysql://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:3306/databasename?user=username &password=password mode=incrementing incrementing.column.name=columnname topic.prefix=MYSQL-databasename-database- –

Comment: Error : Thu Mar 28 09:49:00 IST 2019 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection mus t be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Number of groups must be positive.

Comment: "Number of groups must be positive." -> see https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector.

Answer (score 0):

if you add kafka-connect-jdbc-5.5.1.jar in kafka lib path and restart kafka zookeeper and server. You should able to connect.

Answer (score 0):

You could download Kafka Connect JDBC at https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc which is free and works without Confluent Platform. After unzipping, update the location of confluentinc-kafka-connect-jdbc-5.5.1.jar for the key **plugin.path** in connect-standalone.properties available in the config directory of installed Apache Kafka. The error will go off after running the script again.